# How can I see multiple tabs in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

The situation is when I open some files it isn't added on editor tab(red box).
The file that I double-clicked is located in green box with replacing existing file.

[problem on editor tab in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs8EJ.png)

I want to see multiple tabs in editor tab in IntelliJ.
But I can see just only one tab like below.

I try to look around `settings - Editor - General - Editor tab`. But I couldn't find answer.

I wish I could get a hint here. Thank you.

Comment: Please make sure that the Tab limit is not set to 1 in Settings | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Closing Policy.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov 
umm.. tab limit is already 10.
 The first problem occurred when intellij was updated, but rebooting did not solve the problem.
 I couldn't find a reason, so I just reset all the settings. 
 Thank you for your concerning.

Answer (score 0):

Click on gear on the right -> view options -> Open in a new tab